# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid hex character: v - APNS notnoop

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've been trying to implement the notnoop APNS project in order to send push notifications to iOS devices but I'm receiving this output through the console:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid hex character: v
>       at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.charVal(Utilities.java:133)
>       at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.decodeHex(Utilities.java:120)
>       at com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification.(EnhancedApnsNotification.java:72)
>       at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:54)
>       at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
>       at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:45)
>       at PushServiceTryout.main(PushServiceTryout.java:16)

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong? I can feel I'm almost there! Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here is the code. Anyway, I get the error once I run the program :s

```
import com.notnoop.apns.APNS;
import com.notnoop.apns.ApnsService;

public class PushServiceTryout
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApnsService service = APNS.newService()
                .withCert("c:/fcertificates.p12", "1234")
                .withSandboxDestination()
                .build();
        String msg = "Hello";

        String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody(msg).build();
        String token = "deviceToken";
        service.push(token, payload);
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't include any code, but based on the error, I'd check the device token you are passing. It is supposed to contain only hex characters, and `v` is not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I get the error once is recently running. I don't really get where could be the problem since the device is not really communicating with the program yet :s Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the error:

```
String token = "deviceToken";
```

You can't use the String "deviceToken" as a device token. A device token consists of 64 hex characters (example : "1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef"). Of course, you can't use random hex Strings either. You should use the device tokens sent to you from devices where your app is installed.

You get the exception for the first non hex character in your String, which happens to be `v`.

Comment: I try with a valid devise token string, but also get the above error: `Invalid hex character: Y`.  With devise token: `dtqmzN19fsg:APA91bGddF5IWdSMboqimah1CMEt8j0XN6jwVGDALib-bzv-SBFpMnO9D0HYCbXw0wdvtr7ZrGJJxTx2giTAVraCGkvu4KDaIYmM5-qwkTeTFE9Mhnow4wfJLYEpFg4y3MZ7IkTTQLXG`.